# Exercise frequency

Tags: pull-ups, exercise-frequency

Is doing 10 times 10 pull-ups during ~1 hour 5-6 time a week too often? 
Is it good for keeping current muscle level, combined with the right diet?
Is it necessary to add weight to grow muscles?
What will decreasing frequency and increasing the amount per exercise change?

Comment: What is your goal?

Comment: @masmic trying to lose fat, without losing(or slight gaining) muscles

Comment: That workout is like the one that people who want to oposite (I don't know if is said that way) to enter in the police or similars do. You will achieve dorsal resistance and maybe some development, but isn't the best workout to gain muscle. Is that exercise part of a more extended workout, or is the only thing you're doing?

Comment: @masmic i want at least to keep current musle level, while losing fat, just wanted to know isn't it harmful to do these kind of exercises daily

Comment: If you ever wanted to build muscle I would change your routine. Negatives are also viable if you get "stuck" between your body weight and X#lbs. Negatives focus on the eccentric lengthening of the muscle. In the case of pull ups, you would do the pull up and lower yourself as slowly as possible down to your starting position (then repeat).

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not harmful. You can workout 7 days a week, twice a day if you really feel like it. Just make sure you use good form and if you feel you're getting tired/fatigued really easily and struggling with the workout, take a day or two off to recover/relax. Listen to your body. Make sure you consume enough food and water. High intensity, regular exercise can take its toll on some people - some much quicker than others. Everyone is different.